# Merging json files throwing error: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 376)

Tags: python, json, merge

I am a novice coder trying to work with json files I get from simulations I run in an academic setting. Each time I run a simulation it generates a new json files with many iterations in it.
I have tried a number of different ways to get it to merge and I only was able to get it to print with the following code:

```
import json

i = 'a'
user = 'name'

data = [json.loads(line) for line in open(f'/local/data/{user}/testing_json_merge/testlog{i}.json', 'r')]

print(data)
```

The format of the .json is as follows:

```
# [{
# "target": 0.09812952038889436, 
# "params": {"d_sigma": 0.6090400001793107, "d_tao": 0.38890593065131884, 
# "dq10": -1.9158432178725524, "fk": 0.5920523831391995, 
# "g1": 0.2032381553682863, "gk": 0.22540306720559464, 
# "l1": 0.8194699018730195, "offset": 0.7169580801438833, 
# "zeta": 1.0379064628003654},
# "datetime": {"datetime": "2021-10-01 13:54:23", "elapsed": 0.0, "delta": 0.0}
# }, 

# {
# "target": 0.014074890873478093, 
# "params": {"d_sigma": 0.6482184697214659, "d_tao": 0.5626897579230419, "dq10": -1.0414177520045382, "fk": 0.3709149780460721, 
# "g1": 0.5032815992407432, "gk": 0.9008190120526002, "l1": 0.33090841233049606, "offset": 0.4381149729712961, 
# "zeta": 0.5762116089598821}, "datetime": {"datetime": "2021-10-01 13:54:24", "elapsed": 0.895578, "delta": 0.895578}
# }, ... ]
```

the "..." at the end means this pattern of the format repeats for hundreds of iterations.

I want this to be merged maybe 20-30 of these json files into a single json file with the same format so I can import it back into the simulator to continue later.

Update:
I was thinking and I am pretty sure my .json files are formatted in such a way that they lack a data structure. I think the program I am using is generating one object and stacking it one line at a time with only the next line down as a differentiator. Is there a way to keep this structure but just extend it with the information from the previous one?

Comment: IIRC this is a limit in python's json implementation: it doesn't seem to like loading lists.

Answer (score 1):

You have `.json` file you only need read this file and then load as json object:

```
import json

i = 'a'
user = 'name'

with open(f'/local/data/{user}/testing_json_merge/testlog{i}.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

print(data)
```